# How to reset Tkinter Text widget highlighting in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't find a way to remove previously added highlighting.
For example, a user enters a search query "hello world" and using `search` method in conjunction with `tag_add` and `tag_configure` I highlight text.
However, if a user enters the second query previous highlighting does not get removed. How can I remove the highlighting without reinserting the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `tag_remove`.

Described [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html):

> ```
> .tag_remove(tagName, index1, index2=None)
> ```
>
> Removes the tag named `tagName` from all characters between `index1` and `index2`. If `index2` is omitted, the tag is removed from the single character after `index1`.